# No such file or directory New Relic

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to setup new relic, I have followed the instructions they give however the last command give me this error.

```
newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn wsgi:application
```

why?

```
2013-04-16 10:39:30 [4175] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.5
2013-04-16 10:39:30 [4175] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4175)
2013-04-16 10:39:30 [4175] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-04-16 10:39:30 [4178] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4178
2013-04-16 10:39:30 [4178] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4178)
2013-04-16 10:39:31 [4175] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-04-16 10:39:31 [4175] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions found here:

https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-integration

I'm assuming as this i posted in Django that its a Django app.

add

```
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('/some/path/newrelic.ini')
```